# How enable access files outside htdocs with XAMPP-VM for macOS?

Tags: macos, localhost, htdocs, xampp-vm

With the native XAMPP for macOS I could change the `htdocs` folder very easy to set access files in (e.g.) `/Users/myname/Sites/` and by browser `http://localhost/Sites/`.

How can I do the same with XAMPP-VM for macOS now?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer?